# How to call a .NET DLL from a Win32 process?

Tags: c#, .net, mixed-mode

What are the options when it comes to using a .NET DLL from a Win32 process?
I need to basically use a C# DLL from a Win32 process.

I have a possible solution right now that requires adding the C# DLL to the GAC (using RegAsm.exe), then calling the C# DLL via COM wrapped calls. 
However that solution is pretty heavy.  It requires that the .NET DLL be added to the [GAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx) on all machines that are supposed to run this Win32 process.

Would it be possible to do this without having to call `RegAsm` prior to being able to use the C# DLL?

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the GAC with the Regasm.exe /codebase option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use registration-free COM with .NET COM components - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eew13bza(VS.71).aspx).

Another option is to use C++/CLI as a bridge. People are mostly familiar with using it to wrap unmanaged APIs to expose to managed code, but it actually works both ways - it is possible to compile with `/clr`, and yet produce a `.dll` assembly with plain unmanaged exports, which can be called from unmanaged code as usual. Here's a very simple example that exposes `System::String::ToUpper` that way:

```
// compile with cl.exe /clr /LD wrapper.cpp ole32.lib

#include <windows.h>

__declspec(dllexport)
wchar_t* ToUpper(const wchar_t* wcs)
{
    System::String^ s = gcnew System::String(wcs);
    array<wchar_t>^ chars = s->ToUpper()->ToCharArray();

    size_t size = chars->Length * 2;
    wchar_t* dst = (wchar_t*)CoTaskMemAlloc(size + 2);
    pin_ptr<wchar_t> src = &chars[0];
    memcpy(dst, src, size);
    dst[chars->Length] = 0;
    return dst;
}
```

This will produce `wrapper.dll` - hybrid managed/unmanaged assembly - and an export library `wrapper.lib`. The latter can be used in a pure native application as follows:

```
// compile with cl.exe test.cpp ole32.lib wrapper.lib
// note, no /clr

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

wchar_t* ToUpper(const wchar_t* wcs);

int main()
{
    wchar_t* s = ToUpper(L"foo");  
    wprintf(L"%s", s);
    CoTaskMemFree(s);
}
```

In practice it will load CLR runtime into the calling process (unless it's already loaded there) and dispatch from native code to managed code transparently - all the magic is done by C++/CLI compiler.

Comment: This sounds very good, thank you very much. I'll explore this solution

Comment: *`here`* points to [Configuring .NET-Based Components for Registration-Free Activation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eew13bza(VS.71).aspx) ...in case MS decides to (re)move this...

Answer (score 7):

There are two options.

First, you can use [Registration Free COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1h056h.aspx).

Second, you could use the [CLR Hosting APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx) to directly host the CLR, and load the assembly.  This works without COM.

Comment: CLR hosting APIs can be used indirectly by exploiting C++/CLI - see the update to my answer.